# 'Table doesn't exist' on django makemigrations

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, migration

On a `django 1.11` application which uses `mysql` , I have 3 apps and in one of them I have a 'Country' model:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    countryId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='country_id')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'country'
```

Whaen I try to `makemigrations` I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'dbname.country' doesn't exist")
```

If I run making migration for another app which is not related to this model and its database table using `./manage.py makemigrations another_app`, I still get this error.

Comment: You have module level code which is trying to fetch objects from the database when the module loads before the table has been created. [Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153674/programmingerror-relation-blah-blah-does-not-exist-trying-to-run-the-specifi/45154403#45154403). The full traceback will show you where the lookups are occurring.

Answer (score 5):

I've had this problem and it's because I was initializing a default value somewhere in a model using... the database that I had just dropped. In a nutshell I had something like `forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_some_data(),...)` where `get_some_data()` used the database to retrieve some default values.

I wish you had posted the backtrace because in my case it's pretty obvious by looking at the backtrace that `get_some_data()` was using the orm (using something like `somemodel.objetcs.filter(...)`).

Comment: Thank you, this helped me fix my issue. As soon as I commented out my forms I was able to makemigrations and migrate

Comment: is it possible to have a fix for this without commenting the line out?

Comment: I'm afraid not. If you understood how django works, you wouldn't be asking that :)

Answer (score 4):

Somehow, Django thinks you've already created this table and are now trying to modify it, while in fact you've externally dropped the table and started over. If that's the case, delete all of the files in `migrations` folders belong to your apps and start over with `./manage.py makemigrations`.

Comment: do I need to remove `__init__.py` file in Migrations folder?

Comment: @AlexeiMarinichenko No.

Answer (score 3):

Review, if you have any dependencies, is possible same Model need the Model Country in the same app or other app like:

```
class OtherModel(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

1.- If is True, you need to review if installed_apps in settings.py have the correct order of apps, if is in the same app, you need to declare first a Country app and then the dependents.

2.- If dependent is in the same app, the dependent Model need to be declared after Country model in models.py.

3.- Review if the error track on console talk about same erros on models.py or forms.py

4.- Review if when executing makemigrations and migrate is the correct order of apps: python manage.py makemirgations app_of_country, other_app_name