# How to fix 'Django: table doesn't exist' when migrating from someone else's project?

Tags: mysql, django, django-migrations

I get the following error while trying to run the command `python manage.py makemigrations invigilators`:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'mydatabase.invigilators_shift' doesn't exist")

```
class Shift(models.Model):
    shiftName = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=False,unique=True)
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="shifts")
    startTime = models.TimeField()
    endTime = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shiftName
```

I have already cleared all previous migrations and an empty database is already created.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583744/django-table-doesnt-exist

Comment: You have code that is trying to query the database before `makemigrations` runs. [Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153674/programmingerror-relation-blah-blah-does-not-exist-trying-to-run-the-specifi). To help with your specific problem, you need to show the full traceback which will show where the query is occuring.

Answer (score 2):

Try running these commands

- python manage.py migrate <app_name> zero
- delete all initial.py file under app migrations
- python manage.py makemigrations
- python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 0):

In my case I get the `table doesn't exist` errors from `forms.py`. I then comment out the entries in `forms.py` that refer to a database table. Then I can run `makemigrations` and `migrate`. Then uncomment the lines and everything works. This has plagued me for multiple Django releases.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps solved the problem for me

1. Delete all migrations files
2. python manage.py makemigrations
   (Create your initial migration file 0001_inital.py)
3. python manage.py migrate --fake <app_name> zero

( Tell Django to mark the migrations as having been applied or unapplied, but without actually running the SQL to change your database schema. This brings the migrations to zeroth state. Otherwise Django will think there's no change to apply )

4. python manage.py migrate

Answer (score -1):

**First Step:**
Just "*Cut*" The all *models* from **Models.py** & *paste* that *models* to the any other **text file or notepad**.

**Second Step:**
Just "*Cut*" the all *forms* from **forms.py** & *paste* at the the same text file at you pasted the *Models*.

**Third Step:**
Make a Comment of all imported models & forms in **views.py** Because we don't want errors.

**Fourth Step:**
After these three steps you have to just run the command **"python manage.py migrate".**

**Fifth Step:**
After that command You have to just bring back all the models in **models.py** and all the forms in **forms.py** & uncomment all the imported forms and models of views.py.

**Last Step:**
After these all steps you have to just run another two commands
**1."python manage.py makemigrations"**
**2."python manage.py migrate"**

***& Done,It works.***

Comment: Please avoid such detailed list of steps: "copy", "cut" and "comment" are not useful. Your list cannot be generalized as a good procedure as it is very close to your specific case and very vague "Make a Comment [...] Because we don't want errors". Be simple and provide examples. Hope that my comment can help you :)